# Distinguishing the day change and splitting the next day and time in next day in java

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I have to find the time duration one spend's in a day. I need to give the day asked and the time of entry and exit one spends? I have a table like this.

```
#StartTime#               # EndTime#             # Day #  
2018-07-16 23:00:00    2018-07-17  01:30:00      2018-07-16
2018-07-17 03:00:00    2018-07-17  04:30:00      2018-07-17
2018-07-17 13:00:00    2018-07-17  14:30:00      2018-07-17
2018-07-17 20:00:00    2018-07-17  21:30:00      2018-07-17
2018-07-17 22:00:00    2018-07-18  01:30:00      2018-07-18
```

I need to calculate the exact time he spends in a day asked. For Example, on 2018-07-17. I need both the date and time he spends. The result should be

```
2018-07-17 00:01:00  2018-07-17  01:30:00
2018-07-17 03:00:00  2018-07-17  04:30:00
2018-07-17 13:00:00  2018-07-17  14:30:00
2018-07-17 20:00:00  2018-07-17  21:30:00   
2018-07-17 22:00:00  2018-07-17  23:59:59
```

I am not able to think how can I split the data and how to fetch it from the table. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What's '00:01:00' ?

Comment: I don’t get your requirements, sorry. It seems that if `StartTime` and `EndTime` both fall on `Day`, you just repeat them unchanged in the output. What happens in the other cases? Could you explain better? Are you sure your example result is correct in the last case?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Also your question is broad and seems to have more than one question in it. Try to ask them separately instead. (1) How to retrieve dates and datetimes from MySQL? (2) How to restrict a time interval to one day in Java? (3) How to calculate the duration between two datetimes? Also always search and research before asking, and in the question tell us what your search and research brought up and how it was insufficient. We can help you much better from there, and showing an effort on your part generally meets a much nicer and more helpful attitude from others.

Comment: @Strawberry to me it would be 1 minute after midnight - isnt that for you?

Comment: Retrieve your datetimes into `LocalDateTime` in Java (or better, `ZonedDateTime` if you know the time zone). Your JDBC 4.2 driver can do that directly, search for how. Retrieve `Day` into `LocalDate` in the same way. Use the `day.atStartOfDay()` and `day.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay()` to find midnight at the start and end of the day. Compare to start time and end time and use an `if` statement to pick the relevant output datetime. If you need a duration, use the `Duration` class. Ignore search results that use the long outdated and poorly designed `Date` and/or the `Calendar` class.

Comment: @Strawberry It represents HH:mm:ss means the first minute from mid-night.

Comment: @OleV.V.  Yeah, i got you. I will repeat if the start date and end date falls in the same day. In other cases, If the day is previous to the day asked, then time i have to take when it crosses that day right from mid-night. Which is the case in the first and the last case.In first case, i need from the first minute to the end time in 2018-07-17 and in the last case where the start time is 2018-07-17 22:00:00 and end time i have to take till 2018-07-17  23:59:59 as after this day will change to 2018-07-18.

Comment: What are you using the day for? Your day can be July 16, 17 or 18, but all of your output is on July 17 only?

Comment: So what happens between midnight and one minute past? Why do we exclude that minute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    try (PreparedStatement stmt = yourDbConnection
                    .prepareStatement("select StartTime, EndTime, Day from your_table;");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            findTimeSpentInDay(rs.getObject("StartTime", LocalDateTime.class),
                    rs.getObject("EndTime", LocalDateTime.class),
                    rs.getObject("Day", LocalDate.class));
        }
    }
```

The above snippet uses the following method for finding the times:

```
private static void findTimeSpentInDay(
        LocalDateTime startTime, LocalDateTime endTime, LocalDate day) {
    LocalDateTime startOfDay = day.atStartOfDay();
    LocalDateTime endOfDay = day.plusDays(1).atStartOfDay();
    if (startTime.isBefore(startOfDay)) {
        startTime = startOfDay;
    }
    if (endTime.isAfter(endOfDay)) {
        endTime = endOfDay;
    }
    System.out.println("" + startTime + "  " + endTime);
}
```

Output is not exactly what you said, mostly because I didn’t understand your exact requirements:

> ```
> 2018-07-16T23:00  2018-07-17T00:00
> 2018-07-17T03:00  2018-07-17T04:30
> 2018-07-17T13:00  2018-07-17T14:30
> 2018-07-17T20:00  2018-07-17T21:30
> 2018-07-18T00:00  2018-07-18T01:30
> ```

I think it comes close, and I am leaving to you to adjust the code to the desired.

Disclaimer: The code for fetching from MySQL has been compiled, but I have not run it (not having a MySQL installation at hand). I have run the auxiliary method, and it has produced the output I cited.

You didn’t deserve this answer since your question is both too broad, unclear and poorly researched. I went an extra kilometer to give you at least a bit of an answer. Next time please go an extra kilometer to ask a good question to allow good answers to be written without guessing and too much strain. That will be a pleasure for all, not least yourself.